# accessing dropdownlists from previous page?

Tags: asp.net, .net

In a page I have drop down list which user use to do search. These drop downs are created dynamically from database so there number is not known.

Results are shown in next page which again has all drop downs in it. I need to show selected drop down values from previous page in results page but not sure what can be the best way to access selected drop down values from search page.

Please guide

THANKS :)

Comment: Either store the values in database or in `Session`. You can also use the `PreviousPage` property of the page when you transfer to the next page via `Server.Transfer`.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to build a barn because you have a lot of wood. Use a reusable control and rebind it if you want to keep displaying it, and maybe introduce a caching controller if they aren't likely to update often.

Comment: @jcolebrand I have this in user control and user control is being used on results page. But the thing is how to get state of control that was in previous page ? e.g. I need to show same selections in drop downs.

Comment: Maybe just don't go to a new page for results. AJAX.

Comment: Save it into a form variable in javascript? You're trying to do something rather complicated and there is no easy answer. Whenever I had to do something like this, I just used an updatepanel and suffered the performance hit. Lots of page-state variables too. A LOT of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options. You can either store the values in database or in `Session`.

Another option is to use the [`PreviousPage` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) of the page when you transfer to the next page via [`Server.Transfer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx).

[**Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    DropDownList ddl1 = 
        (DropDownList)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("DropDownList1");
    if (ddl1 != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = ddl1.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work with dynamic controls on the preious page(never tested), you could try to use `Request.Form["DropDownList1"]` to get the value.

Comment: thanks, will it bring controls with last state on page or with initial state when page was loaded ?

Comment: @user576510: You have the last/current state of the controls. You can access them as if  they were in this page via `FindControl`.

Comment: only what was saved into the pagestate, right? Since that was dynamically generated he won't have the pagestate values per-se.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Since they were added to the page's control-collection, it should work (although i have never tested it). I'm also interested in the result. If it doesn't work i would use the session.

Comment: Pretty sure I recall from my past WebForms dev time that it has to be built before the Page_Load event for that to happen. I honestly don't recall anymore.

Comment: @jcolebrand I think it'd have to be in the Page_Init